# Prestashop 1.6 Amount Tampering While Check Out

Tags: php, prestashop, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.6

I have a shopping cart built in Prestashop 1.6 and I have integrated HDFC Payment Gateway in it . After an security audit the bank told me "The test found one high-risk vulnerability (i.e. Amount Tampering)".
Resolution- 
Kindly maintain the session.

I had not coded anything as Prestashop 1.6 is in built CMS and neither did i do anything with the HDFC payment gateway as they provided a pre built code from their end which is developed using Prestashop 1.6. I just installed the module from backend.

The Problem

1. Added one item to the cart and checked out. (eg - 400 USD)
2. On the 3rd party hdfc payment gateway page i didn't process with the payment.
3. Opened another tab and added few more items (eg - 400 USD + 300 USD)
4. Now back to point 2 and i processed with the amount for 400 USD and paid.
5. In my admin panel its showing paid for 400 USD + 300 USD and two items are bought by the customer .

I have no idea how to solve this Amount related issue.

I am a newbie in Prestashop and Payment Gateway Integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice with payment processing is always to double-check that the amount sent back by the bank after the payment was processed is perfectly matching with the amount of the related shopping cart in your local (PrestaShop) database.

**Here's a simplified flow chart:**

[image: PrestaShop / HDFC flow chart]

In case you do not have programming skills, I would suggest to kindly refer to the module's developer so he/she can address that security issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruno , i solved the problem by unsetting the cart id at the time of checkout , so if user opens another tab and adds item a new cart id has been generated. The unsetting is done once user clicks the Confirm my order . It unsets the cart id and processes the page and sends it to the 3rd Party page .

Comment: @ReportGladiatech This works but it's bad user experience. What if a user is redirected to 3rd party and decides he wants to pay with different method? User clicks "Back" and the cart is gone.